# jquery ui datepicker not working with dynamic html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, datepicker

I have successfully attached jquery UI datePicker to a dynamically created textbox, Al works fine excepts when I select a date it is not coming in corresponding textbox, But it comes in my first textbox which is not dynamically created. My code is like this

```
 $(".add-more").click(function () {
        $this = $(this);
        $section = $($("." + $this.attr("data-section"))[0]).html();// This is a section in my HTML with multiple textboxes
        $this.parent().append('<div class=' + $this.attr("data-section") + '>' + $section + '</div>').fadeIn(); 

        $(".datepicker").removeClass('hasDatepicker').datepicker();

    });
```

HTML

```
<div id="Div1" class="section-container">
    <div class="education-item" style="display: none">
        <p>Institute:<input type="text" name="txtInstitute"   /></p>
        <p>Start Year:<input type="text" name="txtStartYear" class="datepicker" /></p>
        <p>End Year:<input type="text" name="txtEndYear"  class="datepicker"/></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/kfLmD/)

Comment: Try http://jsfiddle.net/xUYM2/ ( i just use more accurate indication of elements to create datepicker )

Comment: Ahhh..That work like a charm. You can add this as answer here :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to use more accurate indication of elements to create datepicker. Like here http://jsfiddle.net/xUYM2/

```
$(".add-more").click(function() {
    $this = $(this);
    $section = $($("." + $this.attr("data-section"))[0]).html();
    var block = $('<div class=' + $this.attr("data-section") + '>' + $section + '</div>')
    $this.parent().append(block).fadeIn();

    block.find(".datepicker").removeClass('hasDatepicker').datepicker();
    showHideRemove($(this).parents(".section-container").find(".remove-item"), 1);
});
```

P.S> it will be better to use local variables in you script like

```
    var $this = $(this); // without var keyword your variable will be global
    var $section = $($("." + $this.attr("data-section"))[0]).html();
```

Comment: I have found some issues in your code now, like if i remove the display:none section in the first html, I can't initialise datepicker there.
fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/xUYM2/1/

Comment: Can you please look in to that one

Comment: @Athul add this line at the script start, $(".datepicker").removeClass('hasDatepicker').datepicker(); demo: http://jsfiddle.net/xUYM2/2/

Comment: Oh, sorry. that's cause i remove $(".datepicker").datepicker(); from ini-function.  But than you will get problem.Because datepicker add id to element in wich he laced ( like dp1394890273025 ) - to identify input. And if you will create datepicker object and then duplicate html block - you will copy element id too. And you will get two elements with similar id (dp1394890273025 in my case ). So - this is invalid html and search by id would not work. that is why when you edit new input you have new value at first input like here http://jsfiddle.net/37wj5/

Comment: You must clear id ( or , better, to have clear block of code at template block ) Check possible answer here http://jsfiddle.net/N9eSN/

Comment: @Irvin Dominin aka Edward and you ll get old problem - new inputs work incorrectly

Answer (score 1):

Add this line in the add-more function

```
$(".datepicker").removeClass('hasDatepicker').datepicker();
```